# change_size_with_no_change_in_info

Tags: arrays, matlab

How to increase the size of a matrix. I have a matrix of size 36 rows and 3000 columns. I want to convert it to an array of size 200 rows and 3600 columns without affecting the information contained in the original matrix.

Comment: please mention the programming language..

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language you will need to create the new array and do copy of the previous elements in the new array.
If you are using java i would prefer to use Arraylist.

You can always create 2D array using arrayList in java.Something like this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Type>>
```

But in C/C++ you will need to do entire copy operation.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to work in matlab. Very kind of you if you could suggest some syntax or method to do the same in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this using zero padding.

Assuming matrix `A` has `p` rows and `q` columns and you want to convert it to a matrix `B` having `m` rows and `n` columns (`m>p` and `n>q`). You can use

```
B = padarray(A,[m-p n-q],0,'post');
```

`B` will contain the matrix `A` and the rest of the matrix will be all zeros.

Example:

```
a=randi(10,[2 2]);
a =

10    10
 2     9

b = padarray(a,[4-2 3-2],0,'post');
b =

10    10     0
 2     9     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
```